# To many instances of Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one Activity with Fragment:

```
onCreate()
{
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.container, PostsGaleryFragment.newInstance(), FRAGMENT_TAG).addToBackStack("home")
                            .commit();
}
```

After user's action I call:

```
public void onShowPostRequested(ShowPost pShowPost)
{
    SinglePostFragment singlePostFragment = SinglePostFragment.newInstance(pShowPost.getPostId());

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, singlePostFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

Then navigation can be made backward to home:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
    {
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack();
    } else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

**Problem:**

There is more than one instance of "home" `Fragment`. That is not good for me as every one of those fragments keep lot of references to quite big bitmaps and there is an OOM error waiting just behind the corner.

**Questions:**

Why old instance of Fragment is not used after `.popBackStack()`?
I temporary made a workaround with something like singleton pattern - works ok for now, but are there any disadvantages I should be aware of?

Comment: use replace instead of add. OR remove fragment onDestroy()

Comment: use supportFragmentManager.popBackStack("home");

Comment: also check for savedInstanceState === null on onCreate

Answer (score 1):

i guess what you are missing is check for onSavedInstance, try same as below

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {                     
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.container, PostsGaleryFragment.newInstance(), FRAGMENT_TAG).addToBackStack("home")
                            .commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    onCreate()
    {
       FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
       PostGalleryFragment f = fm.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
       if(f == null) {
         f = fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, 
                   PostsGaleryFragment.newInstance(), FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
   }
```

Comment: This is one of issues here but unfortunately not the right one - I'm testing it without configuration changes, thanks anyway.